# SQL - group on occurence in x or y

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having a hard time making the following to work:

I have a list of transactions consisting of `Sender`,`Recipient`, `Amount` and `Date`.

```
Table: Transactions

Sender   Recipient   Amount    Date
--------------------------------------------------
Jack     Bob         52        2019-04-21 11:06:32
Bob      Jack        12        2019-03-29 12:08:11
Bob      Jill        50        2019-04-19 24:50:26
Jill     Bob         90        2019-03-20 16:34:35
Jill     Jack        81        2019-03-25 12:26:54
Bob      Jenny       53        2019-04-20 09:07:02
Jack     Jenny       5         2019-03-29 06:15:35
```

Now I want to list the people who have participated in transactions, how many transactions they have participated in and the dates of the first and  last transaction they participated in :

```
Result

Person   NUM_TX   First_active               last_active    
------------------------------------------------------------------
Jack     4        2019-03-25 12:26:54        2019-04-21 11:06:32
Bob      5        xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx        xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx
Jill     3        xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx        xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx
Jenny    2        xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx        xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx
```

Using a `group by` statement seems not right - what is the right way to achieve my goal? I'm running on a postgres btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good place to use a lateral join:

```
select v.person, count(*) as num_transactions,
       min(t.date) as first_date,
       max(t.date) as last_date
from transactions t cross join lateral
     (values (sender), (recipient)) v(person)
group by v.person;
```

Comment: Cool, never heard of that! Is a lateral join preferred over a UNION for a big amount of data or should I stick with the UNION-solution then?

Comment: @Crack_David . . . The lateral join -- in particular -- works better on larger amounts of data because it only scans the table once.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff I managed to replace the lateral join with `CROSS APPLY` in SQL Server and obtained the same result. However I'm not sure what exactly does `(values (sender), (recipient)) v(person)` do. I tried to `SELECT * FROM (values (sender), (recipient)) v(person)` but it failed. 

I think you are grabbing the senders and recipients and put them in the same column (as the other answer did but much quicker). But I'm learning `CROSS APPLY` so I'm a bit confused.

SQL fiddle heres; https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4f556a2cb85c4267d3dd25c6b6d8e721

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey . . . If you have a question, it should be asked as a question not a comment.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sure, sorry about this. Let me rephrase it into a question.

Answer (score 4):

You need a UNION to get the 2 columns as 1 column `person` of a resultset and then `group by person`:

```
select 
  t.person Person,
  count(*) NUM_TX,
  min(t.date) First_active,
  max(t.date) Last_active
from (
  select sender person, date from transactions
  union all
  select recipient person, date from transactions
) t
group by t.person
```

Comment: This answer is also working - since I am handling very huge amounts of data the other one is marked as accepted